# riddle about friend of friend

Tags: puzzle

let's say we live in a "very strange" world of Facebook, in which everyone has $1000$ friends. In addition, every $n$ people will have exactly $\lceil{1000 * (\frac{1}{10})^{n-1}}\rceil$ friends in common if $n \leq 3$, not more than a friend if $n$ between (inclusive) $4$ and $1000$ and $0$ otherwise. How many people are there in this world? If there can be more than an answer, what is the lower and upper bound for this number?

PS: Friends and self are excluded from friends of friends.

PS2: I don't know the answer either :)

PS3: Assumed that there must be at least a person in this world

<strike>Edited:Just found a "bug" for this problem, say I'm A and my friends are A1, ..., A1000, friend in common of A, A1, A2, A3, A4 must be subset of friend in common of A1, A2, A3, A4, which is $A$.</strike>

I need to change the statement of the problem... :(

Comment: Did you make this up?  The rounding up does not help.

Comment: The square parenthesis mean the floor function? In that case it is not enough to restrict to $n\leq 4$?

Comment: @Henry: yes I made this up... Well it might not be very helpful, but without it, we may have a non-integer number of friend in common...

Comment: @Student73: no, it was ceiling, actually the ones important is only n=1,2,3, but if I am A and my friends are A1, ..., A1000, there must be friend of common for A1, A2, ..., A1000, which is A, myself :)

Comment: You are right! :)

Comment: Is there a reason to think this state of affairs is even possible?

Comment: @mjqxxxx: it's a riddle, everything can happen in a riddle :)

Comment: Quick question - is *Kevin Bacon* in this world?

Comment: So, every 1000 people have exactly 1 friend in common.  Every 1001 people have exactly 0 friends in common.

Comment: @Graphth: that was the idea...

Comment: bug found (written in the question), if someone can restate the problem (that's still same with my idea), please comment

Comment: @TheChaz: I don't get your question... Is it some kind of joke?

Comment: Yes, it is a joke, but refers to (what could be) a related riddle about degrees of separation between circles of friends.

Comment: And, this is why you don't make up random problems.  But, what you said doesn't make sense.  You haven't told us the friends of $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$, $A_4$, so we don't know who the common friends of those 4 are.  It is true that the common friends of those and $A$ must be a subset of $\{A_1, \ldots, A_{1000}\}$.  But, if $A$ is not included, the friends of $A$ have little to do with it.  I'm sure there is some bug in this problem, but I don't want to figure it out.

Comment: I think it's an interesting question - er - riddle. Reminds me of the research that tried to demonstrate that in a chain of friends there are 6 persons on average in the entire world. So if John Doe wants to pass a message to Obama, the message will on avg pass through 4 more people (if John Doe is not a personal acquaintance of Obama that is...)

Comment: You ought to close this problem, or add a comment to the top at least, so that people don't come here and read through your question only to find you've essentially un-asked it.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: done...

Comment: @zfm: How about this: each person has $1000$ friends; each pair of people has $100$ friends in common; each triplet of people has $10$ friends in common; and every $k$-tuple of people with $k>3$ has *at most* $1$ friend in common.

Comment: @mjqxxxx: very interesting idea! on the other hand, will we have one answer or the answer will be bounded?

Answer (score 3):

Answer to the original problem:  There are no people in this world.  If there is one person, he has 1000 friends.  Choose 4 and call them $a,b,c,d$  They have exactly one mutual friend, call him $e$.  Then $a,b,c,d,e$ have a mutual friend, call him $f$.  But then $f$ is another mutual friend for $a,b,c,d$.

For the new problem, if such a world exists (I suspect not) the population is $9991$.  Choose one individual $a$ and consider how many people are at each distance from $a$.  As $a$ has $1000$ friends, there are $1000$ at distance $1$.  Each of them has $100$ friends among this batch to get $100$ mutual ones with $a$.  So they each have $899$ friends at distance $2$ from $a$, giving $899,000$ edges between distance $1$ and distance $2$ people.  Each person at distance $2$ has $100$ friends at distance $1$ so they have the proper mutual friends with $a$, so there are $8990$ at distance $2$.  There are none farther away, as everybody has $100$ mutual friends with $a$.  As I have not constructed the graph satisfying all the constraints, it may not exist.  They look hard to me.

Comment: this is exactly why I wrote that this problem buggy

Comment: it's no more buggy, I can say that this answer is no longer valid :)

Comment: @zfm:  you don't know that it isn't buggy unless you know an answer.  There may be no solution as stated.  You are right that you have excluded this answer.